# I want to upgrade material-ui from version "0.20.0" to "v1.0.0-beta.26" using command "npm install --save material-ui@next"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am getting the following error.
 npm install --save material-ui@next
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-3d031a97/node_modules/ajv' -> '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/.staging/ajv-eb0b6918'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-56557f45/node_modules/ajv' -> '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/.staging/ajv-bc0c451c'

npm ERR! path /home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/bowser
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/bowser' -> '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/.bowser.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alokkumar/.npm/_logs/2018-01-06T11_49_05_124Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Did you perform what's instructed by the error message?

```
rename '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/bowser' -> '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/.bowser.DELETE'
```

Comment: Yes I performed this one by using the cpmmand " mv bowser .bowser.DELETE" but it shows the 
mv: cannot stat 'bowser': No such file or directory";

Comment: now This error is coming  no such file or directory, rename '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/brcast' -> '/home/alokkumar/my-app2/node_modules/.brcast.DELETE'

Comment: I'd suggest you move your project to a new directory and run npm install there (after removing unnecessary dependencies from package.json).